# Правильно ли это?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мое сердце бьется только для тех людей, которые умеют его слышать. Для остальных у меня нет сердца.

Answer (score 5):

Грамматически - правильно. А с моральной точки зрения - Бог Вам судья. )))

Answer (score 1):

Для остальных — у меня нет сердца. Пропущенные (подразумеваемые) люди заслуживают тире. Если, конечно, не все мосты сожжены.